# Работа с Аудио

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день. Уважаемые гуру, если ли возможность записывать аудио файл и одновременно слышать что именно ты записываешь (Что говоришь) воспроизводить его как-то...

Если есть, то как в этому относиться устройство ? Ему не плохо от этого?
И может у вас есть подобные статьи? Я не нашел в иннете ничего подобного.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aurioTouch из стандартных примеров по objective-c тебе в помощь)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html